# How to prevent multi python scripts to overwrite same file?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, file

I use multiple python scripts that collect data and write it into one single json data file.

It is not possible to combine the scripts.

The writing process is fast and it happens often that errors occur (e.g. some chars at the end duplicate), which is fatal, especially since I am using json format.

Is there a way to prevent a python script to write into a file if there are other script currently trying to write into the file? (It would be absolutely ok, if the data that the python script tries to write into the file gets lost, but it is important that the file syntax does not get somehow 'injured'.)

**Code Snipped:**

This opens the file and retrieves the data:

`data = json.loads(open("data.json").read())`

This appends a new dictionary:

`data.append(new_dict)`

And the old file is overwritten:

`open("data.json","w").write( json.dumps(data) )`

**Info:** `data` is a list which contains dicts.

**Operating System:** The hole process takes place on linux server.

Comment: it's a system-dependent question. On windows local drives, files are locked when written to, so you cannot have concurrent writes. On linux, you can have concurrent writes.

Comment: if you wrote on different files, how would you combine the results? last one wins?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre everything happens on a linux server

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, no merging, last/ or first wins

Comment: is the order important in your `data` variable?

Comment: you could just write data in different files (suffixed by process ID) and combine them together in the end, but if order is important, you would have to sort them by file date (which is also possible)

Comment: Well, yes... at least on a bigger scale. But it wouldn't be a problem if (e.g. from those python scripts who try to write at the same time) some data is a few 'index' away from its original position... the the data of the concurring scripts can be added in any order

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, but it is for some reasons also important that I have only one big file... I dont wont to bother with all the details, but other processes are also continuously using the data in the file

Comment: "It is not possible to combine the scripts." - why not? Especially with a multithreading or multiprocessing approach, you could have one master thread/process that kicks off the other ones and just waits for results.

Comment: Mhh, there is a problem: I dont know how many scripts want to write at the data file at the same time

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you could try to create the file, and bail out if an exception occurs (because file is locked by another script). But on Linux, your approach is bound to fail.

Instead, I would

- write one file per new dictionary, suffixing filename by process ID and a counter
- consuming process(es) don't read a single file, but the sorted files (according to modification time) and build the data from it

So in each script:

```
filename = "data_{}_{}.json".format(os.getpid(),counter)
counter+=1
open(filename ,"w").write( json.dumps(new_dict) )
```

and in the consumers (reading each dict of sorted files in a protected loop):

```
files = sorted(glob.glob("*.json"),key=os.path.getmtime())
data = []
for f in files:
   try:
      with open(f) as fh:
          data.append(json.load(fh))
   except Exception:
       # IO error, malformed json file: ignore
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I will post my own solution, since it works for me:

Every single python script checks (before opening and writing the data file) whether a file called `data_check` exists. If so, the pyhthon script does not try to read and write the file and dismisses the data, that was supposed to be written into the file. If not, the python script creates the file `data_check` and then starts to read and wirte the file. After the writing process is done the file `data_check` is removed.